# correct styling of child element

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following piece of code

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f5345-p2959-o2" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

which relates to a contact form which can be seen by scrolling down to the bottom of the page. You will notice a border at the top of the "form" and i want to remove it.

and the styling associated with this when i debug it includes the following

```
.scheme_dark .wpcf7
border:1px solid #bcd;
```

I am trying to remove the border, but it is proving to be a real pain. The issue is i think the border is attached to the `.wpcf7` class which is associated with many forms on my site, it is only the form with the id of wpcf7-f5345-p2959-o2 which i want to remove the border to.

I have tried all of the following without any luck

```
#wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol > .wpcf7{
    border:0px!important;
}

#wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol .wpcf7{
    border:0px!important;
}

#wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol .scheme_dark .wpcf7{
    border:0px!important;
}

#wpcf7-f5345-p597-o1 form{
    border:0px!important;
}
```

non of the above removes the border.

if i simply use

```
.wpcf7{
    border:0px!important;
}
```

then it removes the border, but also from all my forms

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Post enough of your “*[mcve]*” code - including another form with the same class - to lets us reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure i can as the code is generated by a wordpress plugin, i can post the website if that helps?

Comment: No, take the website code, strip it down to the absolute minimum that lets us reproduce the problem, and post that. Your problems are with the html and css, not the php or server-side processing (so far as I can tell from your question), so none of the php is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply:

```
#wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol
    border:0px!important;
}
```

The thing is, the first three selectors you tried target a `.wpcf7` div *that is inside* a div of ID `wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol`, and your fourth one targets a form element that is inside a div of ID `wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol`. But what I guess you are looking for is targeting the div `#wpcf7-f5345-p597-ol` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) sadly i just tried this and it didn't remove the border :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with no space between the CSS ID and the class and !important is probably not necessary:

```
#wpcf7-f5345-p597.wpcf7{
    border:0px;
}
```

Comment: nope sadly not, still have the border :( thanks for your suggestion

Comment: what if you add !important then?

Answer (score 0):

There is this CSS rule in the stylesheet of the CF7 plugin (visible when inspecting the code):

```
.wpcf7 {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

So to "cancel" that (for that one form only), try to add this to your own stylesheet (the selector combines ID and class):

```
#wpcf7-f5345-p597-o1.wpcf7 {
    border: none;
}
```

P.S.: Note that the last character of the ID is `1`, not `l`, like in some of the examples in your question and in other answers.